# Hyperlink an XML child element with XPath and XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, hyperlink

I have an XML file that stores movies and their actors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="index.xsl"?>
<movies
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="movies.xsd">

<movie movieID="1">
    <actors>
        <actor actorID="1"> 
            <name link="bob.website.com">Bob</name>
            <age>29</age>
            <height>1.75 m</height>
            <from>USA</from>
        </actor>

        <actor actorID="2"> 
            <name link="jack.website.com">Jack</name>
            <age>24</age>
            <height>1.83 m</height>
            <from>UK</from>         
        </actor>

        <actor actorID="3"> 
            <name>James</name>  
        </actor>

        <actor actorID="4"> 
            <name>Tom</name>    
        </actor>

        <actor actorID="5"> 
            <name>Mark</name>   
        </actor>
    </actors>   
</movie>

</movies>
```

As you can see from the code above, I have 5 actors located inside the "movie" element. The first 2 actors contain 4 child elements
(name, age, height and from) as well as the attribute "link" inside the "name" element that provides a hyperlink to the specific actor's page. The other 3 actors only contain the element "name".

I would like my page to display 5 actors' names in a list with the first 2 names displayed as hyperlinks (link to the specific actor's page) and the other 3 to be displayed as regular text.

The way I want to distinguish between a hyperlinked name and a regular name is through XPath.
I want all "actor" elements that contain more than 1 child element (in this case name, age, height and from) to be displayed as hyperlinks. 
All other "actor" elements containing no more than 1 child element to be displayed as regular text

This is my XSLT file containing the Xpath query that I've written.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" media-type="text/html"/>

<xsl:template match="movie">    
    <xsl:text>Actors: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="actors/actor"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="actor">
    <xsl:if test="//actor/*[position()>1]/../name">
        <a href="{@link}">
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        </a>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:element name="br"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have managed to write the query `//actor/*[position()>1]/../name` and I do get only the first 2 actors's names displayed (tested in Xpath notepad++ plugin).
I just don't know how to connect them with the "link" attribute properly and display them on the page.

This is the end result that I want to achieve:

[image: actors image]

The first 2 actors' names are hyperlinked because the "actor" elements contain MORE than 1 child element.
The other 3 "actor" elements only contain 1 child element and therefore their corresponding "names" are displayed as plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely a much easier approach would be simply to apply templates to the `name` elements directly, and distinguish between those that have a `link` attribute and those that don't using separate templates:

```
<xsl:template match="movie">    
    <xsl:text>Actors: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="actors/actor/name"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="name[@link]">
  <a href="{@link}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></a><br/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="name">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/><br/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: That is indeed a much easier approach, Ian. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Alex if you really do want to distinguish based on the number of child elements then you can do that by making the first template `match="actor[count(*) &gt; 1]/name"`, but the `[@link]` version captures the actual semantics better.

Comment: It makes more sense to distinguish child elements based on the "link" attribute, and it's a lot less complicated. But thanks for offering me the second solution as well.